# Excel formula if multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements, formula

I have A2=1000000, I set the following formula at cell b2. I use if have multiple conditions but it is not working. The formula is

```
If(
    A2>=200000, 0%,
    if(
        300000<A2>0.5%，
        if(
            400000<=a2>0.6%%,
            if(
                500000<a2>400000,0.7%,
                if(a2>500000,1%)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Appreciated anyone can help to solve it?

Regards,
Joe

Comment: You need to correct the structure: =if(logical_test1,value_if_true,if(logical_test2,value_if_true,value_if_false))

Comment: Please check your example values: 200000, then up to 3000000, and then down to 400000 and then several trillion? really? and last 500000. Makes no sense at all.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with a lookup table as it is much easier to keep control - as you have found out trying to do your if():

[image]

Comment: Thx Mike. I have typo error on 3000000. It should be 300000.

Comment: @JoeChan so my answer shows the correct value. Why have you not edited and improved your question?